# Does setting of HTTP cookie in ASP.NET Takes time?

Tags: asp.net, cookies, webforms, asp.net-4.0

I am facing a strange problem. I am setting a cookie in one page (`Response.setcookie`), then doing Response.Redirect to another page and there I am accessing cookie (from Request of that page).

Now the problem I am having is sporadic. Sometimes on second page I get the value of the cookie sometimes not. But whenever I am running the application in debugging mode and put a breakpoint between setting the cookie and Redirecting, I am getting the value of cookie on the second page, but not when I run the application normally without any breakpoint.

**Is it that Setting of cookie takes time and so I am not able to fetch when not running in debugging mode?**

**UPDATE**:

I have made thread to sleep for 1-2 seconds and now it does works fine. But the question still remains the same.

Comment: What's the expiration of the cookie?

Comment: Earlier I was not setting any expiration time. (Default is 20 mins rite?). After your comment I tried setting it to 8 hrs, but still same issue.

Comment: What browser are you testing in? Is the issue the same in different browsers?

Comment: IE9 Compat Mode - We do not have any other browser supported in our Intranet (I know its Bad but it is something decided at organizational level).

Comment: I guess this is on your local dev machine, have you tried using the localhost IP Address (http://127.0.0.1/) instead of "localhost", I have had funny problems with IE and cookies and it was due to the domain. I'm clutching at straws to be honest :(

Comment: @PaulieWaulie giving ip is behaving very strangly, application's first page is not loading completly. I tried using hostname of my machine, but still same issue :(